# How to use VISUAL BLOCK to select words of different sizes?

Tags: vim

I think no one ever asked this question.

Say you want to select just the the variables after the `import` word on each line(settings, filters, user, countries, favorites) in this text:

```
import settings from './settings';
import filters from './filters';
import user from './user';
import countries from './countries';
import favorites from './favorites';
```

I tried to put my cursor at the beginning of the `settings` word, press `C-V4jE` but not success. I also tried to apply REGEX after entering in `VISUAL BLOCK` mode, something
like `/\w\s` but yields the same result(a fixed column length block of text):

```
settings 
filters f
user from
countries
favorites
```

The result I'm expecting to do on Vim is this:

```
settings
filters
user
countries
favorites
```

I think I saw this feature on VS Code but after MULTIPLE searches I found 0 results about this solution on Google, everyone shows only how to select fixed column length texts OR just saying to use `$` which applies only for texts that you want to select to the end of the line.

Does anyone knows? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, if you don't get a good answer here there is also a dedicated [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I haven't tried, but probably it can be done with this: https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi

Comment: I'm wondering if this is an X/Y problem? Whatever it is you are trying to achieve using such a selection might have some other vim solution/method? Maybe you could add to your question to explain why you are trying to do this in the first place?

Comment: For instance, if you want to copy these words, you could apply some normal mode commands to all lines (or to a visual range) with `:%norm 0WywG[p` to grab the 2nd word and paste each one at the end of the file and do what you like with them. Or you could make a copy of the lines, visually select them and do `:'<,'>norm dwwd$` to delete the first word, jump to the 3rd and delete the rest of the line, leaving just those words you are trying to select visually in your question.

Comment: Hi @mattb, I wated to copy and paste those variables to paste on a function argument, maybe even automate this action, but I was not able to do so :( I saw your suggestion, it's a great alternative!

Comment: @betoharres ah I get you, I added my comment as an answer for future people.

Answer (score 1):

It's visual-**block** mode: what you select is the whole block, not some arbitrary subset or superset of it.

"Visually selecting" multiple non-contiguous pieces of text of arbitrary length is not something that can be done with built-in means so you can either try some kind of "multi cursor" plugin or approach your problem differently…

For example, if you want to wrap those words in braces because they are no longer default exports, you can do something like this:

```
:'{,'}norm wciw{ <C-v><C-r>" }<CR>
```

Where the normal mode command `wciw{ <C-v><C-r>" }`:

1. move the cursor to next word with `w`,
2. change inner word with `ciw`,
3. insert `{` ,
4. insert content of unnamed register with `<C-r>"` (`<C-v>` is used to insert a literal `^R`),
5. insert `}`,

is executed on each line in range `'{,'}`, representing the current paragraph.

Or, as per your comment, if you want to yank those words for later use, you could do something like:

```
qaq
:'{,'}norm w"Ayiwh"Ayiw
```

Where register `a` is cleared with `qaq` and the normal mode command `w"Ayiwh"Ayiw`:

1. move the cursor to next word with `w`,
2. append it to register `a` with `"Ayiw`,
3. move the cursor to the preceding space with `h`,
4. append it to register `a` with `"Ayiw`,

is executed on each line in range `'{,'}`, representing the current paragraph.

Those things come naturally over time.

Comment: Could you tell me where to find the documentation that describes how `:'{,'}` works?

Comment: Ah I found it in `:help marks`. And now I realise I could have done `:help '}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy
these words, you could apply some normal mode commands to all lines (or to a
visual range) with:

```
:%norm 0WywG[p
```

to grab the 2nd word and paste each one at the end of the file and do what you
like with them:

```
import settings from './settings';
import filters from './filters';
import user from './user';
import countries from './countries';
import favorites from './favorites';

settings 
filters 
user 
countries 
favorites 
filters
```

Or you could make a copy of the lines, visually select them and
do:

```
:'<,'>norm dwwd$
```

to delete the first word, jump to the 3rd and delete the rest of the line,
leaving just those words you are trying to select visually in your question:

```
settings 
filters 
user 
countries 
favorites 
filters
```